# YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Im having some issues with the android youtube api. My code seems to work perfectly the first time i call my youtube intent however whenever I call it a 
second time I only get one second of playback. I call the intent from a simple button in one of my files. All help sincerely appreciated

```
ImageView btnplay_video = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_video);
    btnplay_video.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
            // ShimmerGraphandLogService.class);
            // startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), youtube_player.class);
            intent.putExtra("exercise",exercise_count );
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });
```

This is the youtube layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the youtube java file

```
public class youtube_player extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements OnInitializedListener {
public String[] Exercises = { "Walking on the spot", "Side steps",
        "V-step", "Running on the spot + arm movement", "Side jumps" };
public String[] Youtube_urls = {"FzZcCix_-3k","EIKh0AZGSEQ","pRgnFVAJZe8","R6hCksYs73M","Wx778vK_Lio"};
public String youtube_android_api_key = "AIzaSyCDfKgYduc4sGK9C1weGAIHzsM2LjtvM_M";

private YouTubePlayerView playerView; 
private YouTubePlayer playa;   //hollla


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.youtube_player); 


    playerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
    playerView.initialize(youtube_android_api_key, this);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.youtube_player, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * YouTubePlayerView init listeners
 */
@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error)
{
    Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this,
            "Oh dear, something has gone terribly wrong please try ejecting and re-inserting your diskette", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    playa = player;
    playa.setPlaybackEventListener(new MHPlaybackEventListener());
    playa.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new MHPlayerStateChangeListener());
    playa.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
    int exercise = (int) this.getIntent().getExtras().get("exercise");
    playa.cueVideo(Youtube_urls[exercise]);
    //playa.play();
}


private class MHPlaybackEventListener implements PlaybackEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onBuffering video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onPaused video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onPlaying video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onSeekTo video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onStopped video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private class MHPlayerStateChangeListener implements PlayerStateChangeListener  {

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onAdStarted video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onError video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
        playa.play();
        //pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onLoading video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onVideoEnded video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
        //Toast.makeText(youtube_player.this, "onVideoStarted video...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            this.finish();
            View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);;
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

}

This is the warning/error I receive.

YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView{212125c5 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0a0060 app:id/youtube_player_view}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 (these should all be positive).

Comment: Did you find any solution?